# Return record with no permutation duplicate using SQL

Tags: sql

I was doing an exercise in SQL: list pairs of hacker both won defcon competition were born after 1990. Only list each pair once.

That is, your query should not return both (zix, wix) and (wix, zix).

I have 3 tables

- hackers (name, country, birthday)
- winners (hacker, year)
- white_paper (title, hacker, year)

Hacker references `hackers.name` in both tables --> `winners` and `white_paper`

How can I return names of hacker each pair with no permutation?

My failed attempt:

```
select 
    name, hacker  
from 
    hackers 
join 
    winners on hacker = hackers.name 
where 
    name != hacker
group by 
    country ;
```

Comment: Well, if this is your exercise, what have *you* done?  Copying a question to Stack Overflow isn't much effort.  I removed the incompatible database tags.  You should at least know what database you are using.

Comment: okey  wait i will edit it

Comment: Can you select those, born after 1990? Can you select those, winning defcon? How do you do it? I'm not sure whether I understand the requierement. Pairs of programmers? How are they related? What's the purpose of white_papers?

Comment: @userunknown  ya you should select who is born after 1990 and win the defcon, pair of names ,  every hacker participate in defcon must have a white_papers  and there is a winner  based on the best white_papers so i need to list the winners like (zix, wix) , (x, y) and  (r, z) my problem is the permutation duplicate i don't want ( zix,x) and in other record (x,zix)

Comment: Is every hacker in winners guaranteed to have a match in hacker? Do you have some sample data? Where in your approach is the birthday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  this should work

```
    select A1.name as name1, A2.name as name2
    from hackers A1, hackers A2, winners 
    and winners.hacker = A1.name 
    and winners.hacker = A2.name 
    where A1.birthday > 1990
    and A2.birthday > 1990
    and A1.name > A2.name /* this code is the one who help to avoid duplicate  
 pair  */
```